# missing yum packages for centos 7 when installing vagrant

Tags: centos, vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I have just installed centos 7 and then I try to install vagrant. After installing virtualbox then vagrant when I run vagrant up I get:

```
VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.
```

I run "VBoxManage --version" and i get error

```
The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

I run sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup and I get

```
Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory>
```

What are the missing packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install "gcc" and "kernel-devel" by:

```
sudo yum install gcc kernel-devel
```

then run to recompile virtual box:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

you can now run:

```
vagrant up
```

Answer (score 1):

The step 2 did not work for me:

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found
```

found this one on another thread that worked fine:

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Hoping it help ;)